# curl/curl.h library not found in dev c++ 6.3

Tags: c++, curl, libraries

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
 int main(void)
 {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) 
    {
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");
       /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

       /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
       res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
       /* Check for errors */
       if(res != CURLE_OK)
       fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
       curl_easy_strerror(res));

       /* always cleanup */
       curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
  return 0;
 }`
```

i have linked libcurl.a file in the project and added inlude folder from the curl-7.87.0_1-win64-mingw folder, i have also copied the include in C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Dev-Cpp\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32 folder and copied the libraries too (as suggested in a previous answer to a similar question here) but still it isnt working, the error im seeing is [Error] curl/curl.h: No such file or directory.

this is the code im trying to run